# Android Game Streaming

Tags: android, streaming

My company has it's own line of Android phones, and we are making an application store for the phone. On the store their would be an app for playing our games.

I would like to know if android supports the ability to stream apk games from that app. If so, how could this be done?

What I mean by **streaming games** is that we store the APK on AWS, and the app would then load the url of that apk file and instead of installing it to the device, it would then stream the game (Similar to Flash games or WebGL games for the browser).

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "stream apk games" means.

Comment: I have made revisions, I think that might explain "Streaming apk games" better.

Comment: Android has nothing "out of the box" for this.

Comment: I found AppStream from amazon, I am not sure if that will do what I am looking for or not...